# 3 and higher columnCount cause bug Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-gridlayout, column-count

When objects do not fit in three lines, they go beyond, and I need that if there are too many of them they passed to the next row. Is it possible way to fix it? Thanks.
[columnCount is 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5REr.jpg)
[columnCount is 3 and higher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLUZ1.jpg)

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2">

    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your columnCount is 2 but you have 3 children. Change the columnCount to 3 and see.

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>
    <FrameLayout
         android:layout_width="160dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:layout_columnWeight="1"/>

</GridLayout>
```